# How to open play store from my app and get progress and install result

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I am developing an app that contains the list of apps from the play market and when the user clicks on the download button my app should redirect him to the play store after that when the user clicks on the button install user should be automatically redirected to my app. Is there some way to redirect the user from the play market after clicking on the button install and get the progress of downloading?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Google's Play Store but cannot get progress from this.
Also if the user wants to come back to your application they can navigate using back button but no automated redirection is possible.

There is only limited functionality provided by google play store you can check it [here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play).